# external site loading in fancybox

Tags: coldfusion, fancybox-2

When the following fancybox call is called on a button click, the page does not load, instead, the console shows a message like this.
'Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' . It was loading without error previously.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href            : thirdpartyUrl
    , type          : 'iframe'
    , maxHeight             : maxHeight
    , maxwidth      : maxwidth
    , width         : width
    , height        : height
    , autoSize      : autoSize
    , openEffect    : openEffect
    ,afterClose: function() {
        $('#loaderdiv').hide();
    }
    ,iframe: {
        scrolling : scrolling,
        preload   : true
    }
});
```

Comment: What means `was loading without error previously`? What has changed? Did you modify some setup?

Comment: @User40991 Have you checked the jQuery file and fancybox version? Do you want to update any .js file?

Comment: Not modified any setup recently. Jquery version used is 3.3.1 min and fancybox is 2.1.5